# Should I use MDF or plywood behind my wooden burner?

Tags: plywood, heat, mdf, woodstove, voc

I want to mount a cast iron wooden burner like in the image close to the wall (a double wall with the neighbours, not an outer wall), at about 25-35 cm distance. The exhaust pipe runs vertically.

I would like to mount on the wall behind the burner a thin wooden panel (3 mm), fixed with screws to the wall, on which I will fix round cylinders of wood, to make a sort of artistic thing, and also to hide the darkening of the wall due to increased air movement and to the ashes that may in certain conditions escape. The fixing is likely to be done with some sort of heat resistant, low VOC glue, so that I don't have to remove the panel to add them.

[image]

It is important that the resulting structure stays flush to the wall, without bending due to age or heat, so that the short wooden discs/cylinders will appear like glued directly on the wall. The reason for the panel is only to allow simple removal of the structure in the future.

The panel would be quite full of wood cylinders 10-15 cm in diameter. They would be added in time, whenever available.

I attach a sketch.

[image]

The wooden burner is very hot and cannot be touched with the fingers on the top and top-rear, but the wall is only warmed by the radiant heat. The piping is also quite warm to the touch, but not hot (double walled).

I feel that MDF may hold the shape better after some years, not having any internal structure, but plywood may release far less chemicals in the air.

What is the most suitable material for this application?

**Edit**

The question is about the MDF/plywood plate: which one is best suited to hold some weight (the thin wooden discs) and heat (about 35-40°C) without bending, provided some (6-8) fixing points to the wall, and gassing.

Plywood handles [up to 90°C well](http://www.australply.com.au/technical/thermal-properties).

Comment: Have you purchased the wood burner?  The installation instructions are probably very specific about clearances and material types.

Comment: @Tyson minimum distance from flammable materials is 20 cm on the rear side.

Comment: @Tyson also, no information about the materials that I can use. Only a distance is provided.

Comment: fyi there is such thing as fire retardant mdf.  I'm inclined to think natural wood plywood would look better for what you are doing.  Probably want to go thicker than 3mm though if you want it to stay flat.

Comment: @Alaskaman ok, funny, but if the manufacturer states "20 cm from flammable materials" and I leave 5-10 cm more, I don't see the problem. If you reason the same way you just did, then what is the safe distance? the manufacturer states 70-80 cm from the sides and front. Should I then leave 2 meters from the other pieces of furniture? you see that there are two ways only: follow the manufacturer, or don't install the stove at all. All the other ones are completely arbitrary choices without support.